# FLTK window not showing in while loop c++

Tags: c++11, fltk

I am trying to implement a game loop in FLTK

```
void SnakeFLTK::init() {
    _display = new Fl_Window(900, 600);
    if (!_display)
        throw SnakeFLTKException("Couldn't make fltk window!");
    _display->color(FL_BLACK);
    _display->show();
    while (!_doExit) {
        std::cout << "-->" << std::endl;
    }
    Fl::run();
}
```

the problem I have is the window is not showing. I want to keep showing and redrawing on the window in the `while (!_doExit)` loop and it's important that I use `_doExit`. I have tried using

```
while (Fl::wait > 0)
```

but this method seems to have its own loop that waits for events.
How do I Implement a loop like I did and show the window?

Comment: Oh sorry, Since my question, I have been busy with another lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLTK is doing nothing until `Fl::run` is called. And as this, you can not do anything after you call `Fl::run` because the function returns only if main window is closed.

Exactly for doing something while Fltk itself is "running" you can register to the idle loop like this:

```
void CallbackFunc( void* )
{
    std::cout << "Hallo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto _display = new Fl_Window(900, 600);
    _display->color(FL_BLACK);
    _display->show();
    Fl::add_idle( CallbackFunc );
    Fl::run();
}
```

In the given callback function you can do the drawing or anything youl like to achieve in FLTK which is not driven by events coming from the active widgets itself.